# Is it possible to use the martini framework on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Is it possible to use http://martini.codegangsta.io on Google's app engine? Does anyone have an example? Any gotcha's that I should be aware of before going down this path? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/codegangsta/martini/pull/40

Answer (score 6):

As long as martini does not use cgo or the `unsafe` and `syscall` package [it should be fine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#libraries).
The [README of martini](https://github.com/codegangsta/martini#how-do-i-integrate-with-existing-servers) contains an example of using martini with GAE as [@elithar pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268404/is-it-possible-to-use-the-martini-framework-on-app-engine/20269809#comment30237437_20268404):

```
package hello

import (
  "net/http"
  "github.com/go-martini/martini"
)

func init() {
  m := martini.Classic()
  m.Get("/", func() string {
    return "Hello world!"
  })
  http.Handle("/", m)
}
```

Another example of using third-party packages with app engine is [this randomly chosen app engine example project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-goshorten).